# Accesing LinkedIn API V2 from .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, oauth-2.0

I am building an application that should work with LinkedIn API V2 to make a data provider that will go through authorization process with OAuth2.0 and that will exchange the code with access token in order to make API calls towards LinkedIn in order to access the specific data from the user.

Does anyone know if there is any up-to-date library for easier implementation of LinkedIn API V2 in order to use it within my .NET Application, it is made with WPF (Windows Presentation Forms)

**Basically what I am looking for is something similar to Facebook and Instagram Graph-API, I hope there is or there will be something for LinkedIn, let me know if you have some info!**

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using windows community toolkit, you can find it here: https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Services/Services/LinkedIn  , but it wasn't successful because V1 is not supported anymore and this library is outdated.